# OpenJMS server does not want to start

Tags: java, linux, windows, environment, openjms

I am currently trying to start OpenJMS server and I cant understand why this error occurs. I've tried running it on windows and linux but same error happens each time.
Does anyone have an idea what may be wrong ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$4.run(BuiltinClassLoader.java:711)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$4.run(BuiltinClassLoader.java:706)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:665)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:625)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:593)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:696)
at org.exolab.jms.server.JmsServer.init(JmsServer.java:141)
at org.exolab.jms.server.JmsServer.main(JmsServer.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ls.DocumentLS
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install JDK version 6 for Java 1.6, OpenJMS doesn't work with new JDK installed.